# Replace Regular Expression in Sql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a Table in Sql

Table 1:

========================================

```
ID     Text
1      i am a boy
2      boy!what are you doing?
3      that boy is nice
4      He is a Boy and go to school
```

========================================

i wants to Replace word boy(case insensitively ). like  Replace boy to Man then output show be

Table 2:

========================================

```
ID     Text
1      i am a Man
2      Man!what are you doing?
3      that Man is nice
4      He is a Boy and go to school
```

========================================

what Query i need to write in Sql to do this

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, REPLACE( text, 'boy', 'man' )
```

FROM `table1`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace using Replace command something like this:

```
Update tablename Set Text = replace(Text, 'boy', 'Man');
```

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem you should accept and upvote it.